# How to create an object with a text string that doesn't have quotes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

I'm trying to pass an object to the MongoClient collection.find() method but I don't want quotes around the values. If I pass a literal it works as expected:

```
cursor = collection.find({EmployeeName: {'$regex': /Jo/i}});
```

However, if I try and build that object like:

```
var queryt = "/Jo/i";
var queryo = {
    EmployeeName: {'$regex': queryt}
};
```

It doesn't work. If I do a `console.log(queryo)` I can see that there are quotes around the "Jo/i":

```
{ EmployeeName: { '$regex': '/Jo/i' } }
```

Note that in my application queryt is actually being set by extracting values from the 'query' object that is returned from a 'get' function from express. For example, I am calling the webpage with an ending URL of "?EmployeeName:/Jo/i". In my "get" function I am doing:

```
var queryt=req.query.EmployeeName;
```

So, basically I'm trying to use this node.js app to be a back end server, accepting queries via http get requests.

I've tried various methods of striping the quotes but with no success.

I'm sorry if this is a newbie type question, but I am just learning, and have already spent hours trying to work around it. I'm hoping some more seasoned node.js developer can quickly tell me how to construct this object so collection.find will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the quotes from `var queryt = "/Jo/i";` - currently you're creating a string rather than a regex object. It should be `var queryt = /Jo/i;` as in the first way you showed that worked.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Remove double quotes in `var queryt = "/Jo/i";` this will create string.</strike>

it should be var `queryt = /Jo/i;` this will create regular expression

Update: kcantrel found answer. above method will not work. below method works for him.

```
queryt = RegExp("jo", "i")
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. I need to simply use queryt = RegExp("jo", "i") to convert the string into a regular express, since that is what "find()" is actually expecting.

Comment: @kcantrel cool. can i update my answer with your answer?

Comment: Yes, please. It took me a while to figure out what you were trying to tell me. Not your fault, mine, due to my inexperience. But, once I realize a "regexp" was a specific object, I quickly figured out what I needed to do.